# pthread_create warning on android

Tags: android, c, pthreads, thread-priority

After calling `pthread_create` function I receive next message:

> W/libc    (26409): pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed:
>   Operation not permitted

The code used to create the thread is:

```
pthread_attr_t threadAttr;
int ret = pthread_attr_init(&threadAttr);
//code to check ret - it's 0

size_t guard_size = 0;
pthread_attr_getguardsize(&threadAttr, &guard_size);
ret = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&threadAttr, myStackSize + guard_size);
//code to check ret - it's 0

ret = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadAttr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
//code to check ret - it's 0

ret = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&threadAttr, SCHED_FIFO);
//code to check ret - it's 0

sched_param  schedParam;
schedParam.sched_priority = myPriority; //it's 16
ret = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&threadAttr, &schedParam);
//code to check ret - it's 0

// Create the thread
ret = pthread_create(&myHandle, &threadAttr, RunCallback, (void *)myData);
//code to check ret - it's 0
//code to check myHandle - it's > 0

// Delete attribute
pthread_attr_destroy(&threadAttr);
```

Please note that the message appears in logcat before breakpoint in RunCallback is hit.

Do you know why I have this warning? Is it safe to ignore it - if yes why?

PS: code runs as native activity on Nexus 4 devices with 4.4.2 OS version(build number KOT49H).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `pthread_attr_setschedpolicy`, you're requesting that a specific scheduling policy should be set (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setschedpolicy.3.html). The policy you're setting, `SCHED_FIFO`, is a real-time policy according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html. Setting the scheduling policy to a real-time policy requires the `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html. Therefore, the `pthread_attr_setschedpolicy` call will fail unless you have that capability.

To solve the problem, either drop the scheduler attribute (and live with the default scheduling), or ensure that your process is started with the correct capabilities (e.g. by starting it as root and dropping all privileges except for `CAP_SYS_NICE`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thread is started and runs fine. The only concern I have is the warning.

Comment: 2023 update: now if you compile an Android app with `arm64-v8a` ABI then a call to pthread_attr_setschedpolicy will fail silently then pthread_create will fail but have errno==0 (which should be impossible) and NOT actually start the thread.  So basically you have to just not call pthread_attr_setschedpolicy() at all on Android; you can't just ignore the warning like before. I have NDK `android-ndk-r25c` but no idea when this started.

Answer (score 2):

This error means, that the process trying to create the thread hasn't the appropriate privileges to set the scheduling priorty as specified.

Whether or not you could ignore this warning strongly depends on how the program and its integration in the system depends on the scheduling priorities set for the involved programs/modules/components of the system.

For details on how to set scheduling priorities you might like to [read this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html).