# Using android:fitsSystemWindows="true/false" Navigation drawer height changing and Navigation bar becoming white

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-immersive

I am working on **UnityPlayerActivity** in which camera is rendering on complete screen on top of which, having my Toolbar and Navigation drawer. So I am facing following issues as

Case A : Used android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
Shows navigation drawer but not as expected as height of drawer is not showing fullscreen. 
But android navigation bar is transparent, camera is taking complete screen as
expected.

Case B : Used android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
Shows navigation drawer as expected and drawer height is showing fullscreen.
But android navigation bar is not transparent, so camera is not taking complete screen as expected.

[image: CASE A] [image: CASE B]
[This is my layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvfVd.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you have to be bound with Unityplayer activity or mainActivity.

You can make any activity static and call the function or UI present in those activities from c# unity.

The correct methodology is to create a static Activity in your main Android project and call it currentActivity. After this in your oncreate method you set the currentActivity to this the following code demonstrated that:

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {

 public static MainActivity currentActivity;

 @Override

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         currentActivity=this;
```

In addition : From your Unity code you can use C# to call an Android method from the MainActivity by using the following code:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("yourpackagename.youractivity");

 AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

 jo.Call("toggleMenu");
```

**OR**

You can convert UnityPlayerActivity to Fragment,link mentioned below will help you on same

[How can I open an Android Fragment in a new process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856016/how-can-i-open-an-android-fragment-in-a-new-process)