# Android - embedding Unity3d scene in activity - need to unregister receiver?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've been a SO member for a while but never actually asked a question, so here goes..

### My Aim

I'm trying to make an Android app with two activities. The first is a menu screen (using standard Android UI elements) with a button that opens the gameplay activity. The gameplay activity will have some standard Android UI elements and a FrameLayout containing a Unity 3D scene.

I'm using Unity 5 and Eclipse Luna.

### What I've got working

I've made the menu screen with a simple button to start the second activity. 
I've followed [this tutorial](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-unity-android-in-a-sub-view.98315) and managed to get my Unity scene embedded in my second activity. All good so far...

### The problem

The first time I start the gameplay activity it works fine (I can see the Unity scene embedded in my FrameLayout) but if I close the activity (to return to the menu activity) and then start the gameplay activity again I get this error...

```
Activity has leaked IntentReceiver com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$17@41866de0 that was originally registered here.  Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

### What I've tried

I've done a lot of searching online and it looks like I need to call something like this in **onPause** or **onDestroy**;

```
m_UnityPlayer.currentActivity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

...but **I don't know what the receiver is so I can't reference it in my unregisterReceiver call**. I've tried creating a BroadcastReceiver, registering it and then unregistering it onPause but it makes no difference.

I found [a post on the unity forum](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/402738/how-do-i-use-unregisterreceiver.html) that asks the exact same question but, frustratingly, it is unanswered (a lot of questions on the Unity forum seem to be unanswered, that's why I came here with this question).

I've also tried calling this method in **onDestroy** but it actually quits my whole app when I close the gameplay activity.

```
m_UnityPlayer.quit();
```

### Code Sample

Here's the code for my gameplay activity (I've removed the imports for clarity);

```
public class MyEmbeddedUnityActivity extends Activity {
    private UnityPlayer m_UnityPlayer;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("");
    private BroadcastReceiver bRec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d("", "onReceive intent: " + intent);
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_embedded_unity);

        if(m_UnityPlayer==null){
            m_UnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
            int glesMode = m_UnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
            m_UnityPlayer.init(glesMode, false);

            m_UnityPlayer.currentActivity.registerReceiver(bRec, filter);

            FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_frame);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(200, 300);
            layout.addView(m_UnityPlayer, 0, lp);
        }

    }

    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        m_UnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy (){
        //m_UnityPlayer.quit();
        m_UnityPlayer.currentActivity.unregisterReceiver(bRec);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        m_UnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        m_UnityPlayer.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        m_UnityPlayer.pause();
    }

}
```

### And finally...

The steps I followed to embed the Unity scene were written in 2011.  The whole process (of grabbing the files from the Unity project's staging area and copying files around etc.) seems really **hacky and undocumented**.

Is there a better way of embedding Unity scenes in Android activities with Unity 5? Surely adding a Unity scene to an existing app is a fairly common thing to try to do?

**Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Unfortunately adding Unity3D to existing app is not a common task. If all you need is just one start screen, consider making it with help of Unity UI system.

Comment: thanks for your input Andrey, I did consider using the Unity UI components but I was keen to find a way to do it with native Android UI. As you can see below, I have found the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

So, I did some more searching and eventually found an answer, right here on SO!

As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467994/errors-managing-the-unityplayer-lifecycle-in-a-native-android-application#23541969), adding this line to the manifest fixes the problem;

```
android:process=":UnityKillsMe"
```

so the relevant part of the manifest looks like this;

```
...

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Studio"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:process=":UnityKillsMe"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" > 
    </activity>

...
```

This forces the gameplay activity to launch in a separate process. This means you can call `m_UnityPlayer.quit()` in the activity's `onDestroy` method without the whole app closing.

Simple fix, but annoying that it seems to be completely undocumented.

**Hope this helps someone!**