# Import Unity Classes into Existing Android Project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

As the title says, I have an existing Android project and I want to import Unity classes.jar so I can access the UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535310/how-to-import-unity-project-into-existing-android-studios-project) other question with similar goal, but the answers were unintelligible or unhelpful.

I also found [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-plugin-call-c-from-java.78598/) on the Unity forums, but it is apparently very outdated (2011).

Essentially, all I'm trying to do is:

1. Open up an Android application.
2. Select which scene (or, preferably, more than one scene) I want to view from the Unity app.
3. Launch the Unity GearVR application.
4. Play the selected scene(s).

I've already got steps 1 and 3 working, and steps 2 and 4 I'm making work by loading each scene up as a different APK and launching a specific APK depending on which scene I want to view, but, ideally, I could host all the scenes in a single application so I could then watch several off the scenes in a row (and also so I could cut down significantly on memory usage).

I've found some tutorials on using UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage, so I think I can get it working if I can only get Android Studio to recognize and use UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage, but if you have any other ideas, I appreciate those as well!

Answer (score 0):

> I've found some tutorials on using UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage, so I
>   think I can get it working if I can only get Android Studio to
>   recognize and use UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage

Get classes.jar from one of the sub-folders from

```
<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono
```

or

```
<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp
```

depending on if you are using mono or IL2CPP as Scripting Backend to build your Android Project.

Import it into Android Studio. Right-click on it and click **Add As library** and Android Studio should add it as library. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681629/3785314) if you are still confused. You can now use `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage`.

As for the rest of your question, I think that you should look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43921522/3785314) answer. It explains how you can show Unity scene in a sub-view. That is another way to get what you want.