# Unable to resolve dependency error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've imported a unity android project as module to my existing android studio project and came up with these errors while gradle syncing.

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :markerlessAR1.
>   Open File
> Show Details

Comment: Please provide your build.gradle(app).

Comment: Could you please share your build.gradle file.

Comment: having the same issue. :( have you fixed this?

Comment: please tell us how you added the Unity project, and show your build.gradle and settings.gradle files

Comment: I think your problem related to import Unity project to Android Studio Project. You can read at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535310/how-to-import-unity-project-into-existing-android-studios-project. Hope it's useful for you

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the case on my end. The classes.jar was **missing** from my AAR file (didn't find that .jar when I 'unzipped' the AAR). So what I did was I rebuilt my AAR file by re-executing `gradlew assemble` and then imported this new AAR into my Android application project.

As for why the classes.jar was missing from my first AAR file, I have yet to uncover the mystery of that. I think I forgot to execute the gradle command and just picked the available AAR file from the newly created Android module out of the Unity-exported application project (because I was too excited).

Answer (score 2):

Try below steps to resolve this error:

1) Import AAR file in native android app from  File -> Project structure -> add new aar package.

2) After successfully synced,make sure that your AAR module contain build.gradle file.
   For example: UnityAAR is your module name containing unityaar.aar file, build.gradle file.

3) If module gradle file is missing, add on your own. Gradle file contains
   configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('unityaar.aar'))