# How to Display UnityPlayer inside my android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine

I got a UnityPlayer app for android, I imported it into my android studio it was running as a unity app. 
But I want to run this inside my another android's main activity?
I gone through some sites with no use can any one help me out. (In android studio not 'Eclipse').

Edit: I want to know how to display this unity app inside my another android apps view in main activity? in Android studio.

Comment: If you think that You can use Unity3d Inside an Activity of an Android Activity as a Sub Activity of the Main. I am sorry my Friend it is not possible. As Unity3d uses OpenGL api. and cannot be run on any Activity even for Android. It is just simple Runs from 2 Different Shells of Android with the same Signature of the app but 2 different Service call.

Comment: Check this link, http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-unity-android-in-a-sub-view.98315/ and this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467994/errors-managing-the-unityplayer-lifecycle-in-a-native-android-application/23541969#23541969