# I want to create a native Android and iOS app including Unity AR

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, augmented-reality

The fact is that I wasn't able to find documentation or tutorials about how do this. The app is completely native and it just contains one or two views that needs the Unity AR. In this case I should create the projects from Unity and edit them from XCode and Android Studio? Or I can create it and then add the Unity part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467994/errors-managing-the-unityplayer-lifecycle-in-a-native-android-application/23541969#23541969) :

For **Android** you have to follow 3 steps :

- Build your Android project (select *Android* platform and enable
  *Google Android project*)
- Import your built project to Android Studio
- Do what you want inside Android Studio and build

For **iOS** I guess it's quite the same process using *views* but never went into it.