# Passing data from Unity to a native app - how to?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

### I have two applications

> Native Android Application (Say NAA)
>
> Unity Game (Say UG)

I want to integrate the unity game(UG) into the Native Android Application (NAA)

I exported the unity game into android which is converted into .aar library and I am able to integrate the UG into NAA. But I want to send the unity game score to native android application.

> AndroidManagerScript.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AndroidManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private AndroidJavaObject curActivity;
    public string strLog = "No Java Log";
    static AndroidManager _instance;
    public Text _text;
    public static AndroidManager GetInstance()
    {
        if( _instance == null )
        {
            _instance = new GameObject("AndroidManager").AddComponent<AndroidManager>();   
        }
        return _instance;
    }
    void Awake()
    {

        #if UNITY_ANDROID 
        AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        //AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("great.good.com.rolauncher");
        curActivity = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        #endif


        _text = (Text)GameObject.Find ("Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
        _text.text = strLog;
    }
    void Start ()
    {
    }
    public void CallJavaFunc( string strFuncName, string strTemp )
    {
        if( curActivity == null )
        {
            strLog = curActivity + " is null";
            return;
        }

        strLog = "Before call " + strFuncName;
        //curActivity.Call(strFuncName, new object[] { strTemp } );

        curActivity.Call( strFuncName, strTemp );
        strLog = strFuncName + " is Called with param " + strTemp;
    }
    void SetJavaLog(string strJavaLog)
    {
        strLog = strJavaLog;
        _text.text = strLog;
    }
}
```

> I am calling a function javaTestFunc on game exit

```
public void GQuit()
        {
            AndroidManager.GetInstance().CallJavaFunc( "javaTestFunc", "UnityJavaJarTest" );
            
            Application.Quit();
        }
```

> Native Android Code

```
import com.Hash.FC.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class MainActivity extends com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity {

    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        Log.e("data","start");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void javaTestFunc(String strFromUnity) {

        //java to unity
        //UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("AndroidManager", "SetJavaLog", strFromUnity + "HelloWorld");
        Log.e("data",strFromUnity);

    }

    public static void testMethod(){
        Log.e("data","data");
    }
}
```

> JavaTestFunc is not triggering. Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to just save data in the persistentDataPath:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html

and read that folder from your native app.
I'm not sure about the limitation of this since I just use Unity3d with a native PC application (I'm not sure it is possible to read the persistentDataPath that is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data//files on android with another app) but if it is possible you will just need to read data from there from your native app and write data there from your unity app.